# Swing EditorPane Scala size not working

Tags: swing, scala

I have created the below EditorPane with scala.Swing

```
import scala.swing.{Font, Color, EditorPane}

val textArea = new EditorPane() {
  font       = new Font("monospaced", java.awt.Font.PLAIN , 20 )
  background = Color.darkGray 
  foreground = Color.magenta 
  size       = new java.awt.Dimension(30,50)
}
```

Running the above code generates the error:

```
value size_= is not a member of scala.swing.EditorPane
```

In the scala.swing EditorPane API (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/index.html#scala.swing.EditorPane) it refers to size as being `java.awt.Dimension` So I can not see why my code is wrong. I also tried `size.setSize(30,50)` , it compiles but the EditorPane has only one line which means that the size is not being set correctly.

What is the problem here?

ps : I have the latest Scala Version.

Comment: Don't know much about scala (I do know swing), but why don't you invoke the `java.awt.Dimension` constructor instead of its `setSize()` method? `new java.awt.Dimension(30,50)`. Maybe that's causing your error.

Comment: No... Still can not get it right.

Comment: Still he is correct. The Dimension class has no static method `setSize`. You can only invoke `setSize(d: Dimension): void` on an already existing `Dimension`. It does also not return a `Dimension`. In conclusion it should be `size = new Dimension(30,50)`

Answer (score 0):

`EditorPane` inherits like all components from `UIElement`.

`UIElement` provides related setter methods like:

```
minimumSize_=(x: Dimension)
maximumSize_=(x: Dimension)
preferredSize_=(x: Dimension)
```

There is also a `size` method, but no setter for it. That explains your error.

My personal interpretation:

In the end, the Layoutmanager will deal with the sizes of all components and you should not manually interfere. You can state your wishes with the minimum, maximum and preferred size.

The only classes where you can directly set the size are windows and frames.

```
new MainFrame() { size = new Dimension(30,50) }
```

Comment: I can not understand what hack workaround means :) . But my program looks like this http://prntscr.com/4dznyn

Comment: If you want, you can upload your complete code here: http://pastebin.com/ and I'll have a look. Seems to be something with the layout.

Comment: If this (http://prntscr.com/4e01z9) is what you wanted, here is what I changed (http://pastebin.com/fpbWtzet). You should maybe look more into different layout panels and combine them to get what you want.